# What's the difference between the CardView from com.google.android.material and android.support.v7.widget

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android, material-components, cardview

I'd like to know the difference between both widgets `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` which is added using Android Studio IDE components palette and `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` which is used on Material Design documentation.

Are they two libraries that contains the same widget? Which one should I use and how to take this decision?

I tried to read more the developers.android documentation, but the docs on developer.android are really big with many version and I'm yet a bit confused and couldn't find a good explanation between all of these versions, the history of it all and how it got there. Does someone feel happy to gives me a insight about this history?

**Material design documentation usage:**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Source: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/

**The CardView XML added when using Android Studio:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: That's material layout with much more clean look.

Comment: So, is it recommended to use android.support/androidx (as I read, the version that the old support library) instead of following the material guide that uses com.google.android.material?

Comment: No I also recommend Material themes. I was just explaining what's different in material and support library.

Comment: Note that `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` extends `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`. See https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.html

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are 3 versions:

- `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`: it is provided by the old support libraries and it is deprecated.
- **`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`** it is the **androidx** version and it replaced the support libraries.
  To use it you have to add the dependency `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:x.x.x'`.
- **`com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`** is provided by the **Material Components Library**. 
  To use it you have to add the dependency implementation
  `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`.

The `MaterialCardView` **extends** the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and 
introduces some changes as the use of a  **[`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable)** as background  (it allows [shaping](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) and [elevation overlays for Dark Themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays)).
Also `MaterialCardView` supports [checking](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-checkable) and [dragging](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-draggable).

Comment: This should be as the best answer. It provides all the context to fully understand the differences between this components.

Comment: `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` also has a foreground selector by default.

Answer (score 18):

I made a research in the last days about the history of Android libraries and I've got a conclusion that I'd like to share:

> 1. The component android.support.v7.widget.CardView is part of an old library and it's recommended to be replaced with
>      com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
> 2. Android support library (android.support.*) is an old library that was replace by the new Android X Library in 2018 (which is part of Jetpack Library) and also by material components android

**References:**

https://medium.com/@neerajmoudgil/upgrading-to-new-android-material-design-components-e62ddb03c3d2

https://developer.android.com/reference (It's big, but worth to take a look for beginners who would like to understand the history of Android Libraries and also about all of the Android Versions)

Comment: What about `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`?

Comment: It is a androidx version of android.cardview @argenkiwi

Answer (score 8):

According to [Material Design docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/)

> MaterialCardView is a customizable component based on CardView from the Android Support Library. MaterialCardView provides all of the features of CardView, but adds attributes for customizing the stroke and uses an updated Material style by default.