# What is difference of material cardview and just cardview? and why some attrs do not applied?

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android

for example I added elevation attr to `MaterialCardView`, but it doesn't work. and also customizing with `background.xml` doesn't work. why it happens. and what is better to use? between them

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you tried ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference is the use of a [`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) as background implementing some Material features, such as [shaping](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) and [elevation overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) for Dark Themes.
Also `MaterialCardView` supports [checking](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-checkable) and [dragging](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-draggable).

About the **elevation** use the `app:cardElevation` attribute.
About the **background** check your log.You should have an [info message:](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.java#L338) `"Setting a custom background is not supported."`

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700587/8144311) has usefull information about difference of card view and material card view .
and answer to second question :
Using material components require material components theme.
Make sure to use material theme in your project to be able to customize view.

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

about the elevation,use `app:cardElevation` instead
 and about background,use `app:cardBackgroundColor`