# CardView error: Cannot resolve class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm trying to use cardview with my recyclerview. The recycler view works on its own. I've got it set up with databinding. But I wanted the recyclerview to look better which is why I'm wanting to use cardview with it.

This is my layout file for individual views:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="individualEntry"
        type="com.zebotek.balancedmindjournal.persistance.JournalEntryDataClass" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:dateStringFormatted="@{individualEntry}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/journalEntryTextBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:journalEntryText="@{individualEntry}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTextBox" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my dependencies:

```
cardView_version = '28.0.0'    

implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$cardView_version"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$cardView_version"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$cardView_version"
```

I can't identify anything that I could do differently. I have minSdkVersion set at 21.

The code works just fine without the cardview. If I add the cardview, now it won't compile and I get that error. I've even tried placing the cardview above the constraintlayout. I've replaced the constraintlayout with the cardview and even replaced the top level layout with the cardview.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974226/2016562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use
`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`, instead of `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

And add [dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview):

```
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Adding the change to use androidx.cardview.widget.CardView along with the dependency solved the problem. What's really confusing about all this, to me, is that I can't find this (along with the dependency you mentioned) anywhere in android documentation.

Comment: `support.v7.*` or `support.v4.*` are no longer maintained. They all have migrated to `androidx`. I recommend to you research about **backward compatibility** and [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

Comment: Migrating to AndroidX is not always a viable option

Answer (score 1):

If you use androidx(It is seen in your first layout), I still recommend using [CardView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview) from AndroidX

just import in yout build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
}
```

Another recommendation is to remove the ConstraintLayout and leave only CardView